# reduce number of round trips - linq-to-sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2, foreach

Is it possible to reduce the number of round trips to the database during the execution of an asp.net mvc 2 action for the following specific case and in general?
I'm using linq-to-sql.
The following code results in something like 60 selects, which take 60 round trips to the database. How can I reduce the number of round trips ?

If more of my code is needed, I will post it.

My view model :

```
public class ArticlesContainerViewModel
{
    public ArticlesContainerViewModel()
    {
    }

    public Article CategoryArticle { get; set; }

    public IList<ArticlesNode> CategoryNodes { get; set; }
}

public class ArticlesNode
{
    public Article NodeArticle { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<Article> NodeItems { get; set; }
}
```

The view:

```
<ul class="tabs">
        <% foreach (var category in Model)
           { %>
        <li><a href="#" class="s">
            <%= Html.Encode(category.CategoryArticle.AbbreviatedTitle) %></a></li>
        <% } %>
    </ul>
    <!-- tab "panes" -->
    <div class="panes">
        <% foreach (var category in Model)
           {
        %>
        <div>
            <table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <% int counter = 0; foreach (var node in category.CategoryNodes)
                   {
                %>
                <%if (counter % 2 == 0)
                  { %>
                <tr>
                    <%} %>
                    <td class="content-container">
                        <div class="index-node-title">
                            <%= Html.Encode(node.NodeArticle.ArticleTitle)%>&nbsp;<span class="small1 darkGrey2">(<%= Html.Encode(node.NodeItems.Count().ToString())%>)</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="index-node-content">
                            <ul class="index-node-content-list">
                                <% foreach (var item in node.NodeItems.Take(2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is a little bit messy if you ask me, and I guess that the type of `Model` is of type `IList<ArticlesContainerViewModel>` or something similar. Your problem is that you are using `IQueryable` this "high" up in the application. The structure I would go for is:

```
1. First select all categories and put that in your `ViewModel` using a single query. 
2. From all your categories select all your articles or what else from the db in a single query, put the result in a dictionary where category is the key.
```

That way you should be able to get only two queries instead of `m*(n+1)` as you are having now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PLINQO.  It will optimize your queries.  [www.plinqo.com](http://www.plinqo.com)